# Wordpress slow/unresponsive and nothing changed.

Tags: wordpress

It was just slow and couldn't edit pages. I disabled the plugins and that didn't help. I now at login screen get this error after 20s of loading.

[Table 'safaridr_wordpress.wp_redirection_items' doesn't exist].....

The theme is fine as I tested it on anther site.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the plugins conflict.
Turn-off all the plugins, add this lines to your wp-config.php file and try to debug the issue:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```